# Counting rows in multiple tables then output

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have about 100 tables in Access and wish to see the total number of rows that each contains, together with the table, without explicitly defining the table names.

For example, if I have:
Table1 which contains 200 rows,
Table2 which contains 500 rows,
.
.
.
TableX which contains y rows

Is there a combination of vba/sql that can generate a new table where left(tablename,5) = 'Table' showing:
TableName, RowCount
Table1, 200
etc

And can it be modified to also work on queries rather than tables

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple query to select the information you want, and insert it into a new table:

```
SELECT MSysObjects.Name, DCount("*",[Name]) AS RowCount INTO SomeTable
FROM MSysObjects
WHERE MSysObjects.Type=1 AND Name LIKE "Table*"
```

For queries, you can change it to `MSysObjects.Type = 5`

Comment: This did not work for me in MS Access 2016, throwing the error: Compile error. in query expression 'DCount("*",[Name]'.

Comment: That's not an [mre] and you can't get compile errors when building queries in Access (just syntax errors), so you must be doing something strange...